# iOS PWA splash screen?

Tags: ios, splash-screen, progressive-web-apps

In terms of PWA splash screens, do people think the code at https://pwa-splash.now.sh/ and https://medium.com/@applification/progressive-web-app-splash-screens-80340b45d210

is the most up-to-date and device compatible way of doing it? Or have people found issues with it and have modifications?

Here is the code:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash/launch-640x1136.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash/launch-750x1294.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash/launch-1242x2148.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash/launch-1125x2436.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash/launch-1536x2048.png" media="(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash/launch-1668x2224.png" media="(min-device-width: 834px) and (max-device-width: 834px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash/launch-2048x2732.png" media="(min-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)">
```

**Update 1:**

In response to the answer by Robinyo below, taking the first example above:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash/launch-640x1136.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)">
```

The following line would need to be added for landscape yes?

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash/launch-**1136x640**.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: **landscape**)">
```

Perhaps I’m wrong but I’m actually not sure whether iOS PWA will handle it. The reason is because I read that on creation (Add to home screen), iOS selects one png and stores it locally. So the next time the PWA app is opened it uses that one local image before trying to connect to the web. So the question I’m wondering about is whether iOS will store two images locally, one for portrait and one for landscape.

Comment: For anyone looking, I was using this generator: https://appsco.pe/developer/splash-screens for my splash screens and they forgot this sizing: (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) in the code it generates for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of April 30, 2019, https://gist.github.com/EvanBacon/7fd4dc3be3d00096579bb0b134c56ec7 worked (tested in iPad Pro 11 inch, iPhone XS Max) including both portrait and landscape.

**Update November 12, 2020:**

(I haven't tested on any of the 2020 devices listed. If someone has, please feel free to advise)

```
<!-- Apple Launch Screen Start -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/1.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/2.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/3.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/4.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/5.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/6.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/7.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/8.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/9.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/10.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/11.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/12.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/13.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/14.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (width: 834px) and (height: 1194px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/15.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/16.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/17.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (width: 834px) and (height: 1194px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/18.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/19.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/20.png">

<!-- 2020 Start -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 810px) and (device-height: 1080px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/21.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 810px) and (device-height: 1080px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/22.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 820px) and (device-height: 1180px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/23.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 820px) and (device-height: 1180px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/24.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 428px) and (device-height: 926px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/25.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 428px) and (device-height: 926px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/26.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 780px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/27.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 780px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/28.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 390px) and (device-height: 844px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/29.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 390px) and (device-height: 844px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="/pages/splash-screen/images/30.png">
<!-- 2020 End -->

<!-- Apple Launch Screen End -->
```

Comment: I'm also looking the proper way to do this. It seems that this is the latest working code, but device width property is deprecated? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width

Comment: @Shnigi Even though Mozilla says it is, I tried using width instead of device-width as shown in the November 2020 update above. My iPad Pro 11 inch didn't recognise it and just displayed a white screen.

Comment: @Shnigi And BTW, width was used to temporarily not use that line because of https://github.com/onderceylan/pwa-asset-generator/issues/93

Answer (score 6):

For those still wondering about this, I've created a [free tool that generates iOS splash screens](https://progressier.com/pwa-icons-and-ios-splash-screen-generator) in all sizes (there are 26 of them as of April 2022) along with all the necessary meta tags (both portrait and landscape).

Right now, it supports every screen size all the way to the most recent iPhone 13 Pro Max. Tested on every single iPhone and iPad available on Browserstack.

The appsco.pe link mentioned in this thread doesn't provide splash screens for the latest devices and it's also missing landscape versions.

The tool itself is free to use but it shares the same code that I use for a commercial product, so by design, it should always be up-to-date.

Comment: Did your testing notice https://github.com/onderceylan/pwa-asset-generator/issues/93 ?

Comment: It did. But I don't think there is any possible way around this, besides waiting for Apple to eventually fix it.

Comment: This tool worked for me, thank you! The others that I've used did not generate ALL of the required images.

Answer (score 1):

For quick testing go to [ios-splash-screen-with-generate-link-tag](https://appsco.pe/developer/splash-screens) to generate your splash screens along with the auto-generated link tags,

your link tags should look these this with `orientation` present,

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/apple-launch-1125x2436.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/apple-launch-750x1334.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/apple-launch-1242x2208.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/apple-launch-640x1136.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/apple-launch-1536x2048.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/apple-launch-1668x2224.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/apple-launch-2048x2732.png">
```

In addition, make sure to have these header tags set,

```
  <link rel='apple-touch-icon' href='/pwa/512.png'> 
  <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes"> 
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="your_title">
```

Make sure to use the correct paths in the `href` attributes above!

Answer (score 0):

The key moment is to set all splashes with correct resolutions.
Also one must not use `link rel="apple-touch-startup-image"` without `media`. If this tag is after all counterparts with `media` then it will be used for all resolutions. But if screen resolution differs from image resolution then the configuration is skipped.

Don't change `device-width` to `width`. `screen` in media is not necessary.
`px` is resolution is obligatory.

For example, for iPhone 13 Pro Max one needs

```
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" 
        media="(device-width: 428px) and (device-height: 926px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" 
        href="/ios-launchimage-1284-2778.png"
    />
```

where launchimage-1284-2778.png must have (1284px, 2778px) portrait resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Apple keeps releasing new devices every year with different screen sizes and the `<meta>` tags in the `<head>` section of my website kept increasing. So I wrote this simple script ([iosPWASplash](https://github.com/avadhesh18/iosPWASplash)) to automatically generate the splash screen based on screen size using `Canvas` and add it to the page.

You just need to provide an icon file (preferably a PNG of 512x512) and a background color.

Here is some example code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ios-pwa-splash@1.0.0/cdn.min.js"></script>
<script>iosPWASplash('icon.png', '#000000');</script>
```